# How to get the value of an option which begins with '+' character?

Tags: c, bash, c99, getopt, getopt-long

I am writing an option parser for a bash-like shell I develop.

Nevertheless, to be compatible with bash options, I must read some options which begin with a '+', like this:

`./42sh +O autocd [...]`

(The manual page says these options will passed to the builtin `shopt` which sets the values of settings).

The problem is that `getopt_long()` function only returns the options which begin with a `-` or `--`, if they are not alone. If they are, bash counsider them respectively as an alias for standard input and a end of options marker.

How I could get this type of options with `getopt_long()` ? Have I to parse these options by myself ?

EDIT : according to the @jxh response and the `man 3 getopt` page, I discovered that `getopt` and `getopt_long` arranges the `**argv` parameters array to move all arguments that don't seem to be valid options - from their point of view - at the end. So, I wrote the following code after the usual code which gets the *normal* options (all suggestions and remarks greatly appreciated):

EDIT2 : fixed memory leak due to strdup() at each iteration of the loop.

```
for(; optind < argc; ++optind)
{
    const char *argv_copy = strdup(argv[optind]);
    if (argv_copy[0] == '+' && argv_copy[1] == 'O')
    {
        /* A deactivation parameter have been just found ! */
        if (handle_shopt_options(shell_options,
                                 argv[optind + 1],
                                 DISABLE) == EXIT_FAILURE)
        {
            usage(argv[optind]);
            free_shell_options(shell_options);
            shell_options = NULL;
        }
            ++optind;
    }
    free(argv_copy);
    argv_copy = NULL;
}
```

Some explanations:

- `optind` is the `argv` index which tells us which argument **will** be parsed at the next pass. Since we parsed all the getopt() point-of-view valid arguments, and since getopt() moves all the non-options at the end, we will parse all remaining arguments, included the ones which interest us.
- `argv[argc] == NULL` : this trick is used to know where is the end of the arguments list, so it is useless to parse the argument when `optind == argc`.
- I am not comfortable to play directly with the current `argv` value, so I preferred to copy it in a new string, but I am probably wrong, to be verfied.

Some remarks:

- `getopt_long()` will be available only if `_GNU_SOURCE` macro is defined.
- `strdup()` will be available only if macro `_XOPEN_SOURCE >= 500` or macro `_POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 200809L`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you have noted in your research, you cannot use `getopt_long` to parse options that begin with `+`.

As a workaround, you can scan `argv[]` yourself, and then create a new argument vector that substitutes `--plus-` in front of every argument you think is a `+` style option in the original `argv[]`. This new array should be parseable by `getopt_long`.

Comment: By the time the code has went through the work of scanning `argv[]`  is should have already acquired all the arguments and each found argument can be immediately processed into the appropriate flags within the program.  So no need to create a new array

Comment: @user3629249 The idea is to write a small amount of code to perform a simple substitution, and then leverage `getopt` to do the actual argument processing.

Comment: Can you tell me how to create a new argument vector? We can't just prepend to the corresponding `argv[i]`, can we? I mean, it would disturb the array?

Comment: @J...S: Yes, don't modify the strings in `argv[]`. Instead, allocate new strings for the ones you plan to change. You can overwrite the old entries with the new ones if you wish onto the original `argv[]`, but it might be more clear to instead create a `new_argv[]`.